# facebook pagination using next() URL error

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, pagination

I am working on facebook pagination, I have searched but didn't get relevant answer.
First I am fetching 10 result and after that `onclick` function I want to fetch next 10 results for this I am passing -

[paging] =>

Array
(

```
    [previous] => https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/....D&__previous=1

    [next] => https://graph.facebook.com/........
```

)

as parameter,I also tried passing next URL as parameter but still it is not working, if I pass $feedEdge as associated I am getting response as null,below is my code

```
$response = self::$_FBINSTANCE->get('/me/feed?fields=id,message&limit=' . $_pagination->limit); 

        if(empty($_nextFeed)){ 
            $feedEdge = $response->getGraphEdge();
            $nextFeed = $response->getGraphEdge()->getMetaData();
        }else{
            $feedEdge=$response->next($_nextFeed);
            $nextFeed = $response->getGraphEdge()->getMetaData();
        }
        $result = array();
        foreach ($feedEdge as $status) {
          $result[] = $status->asArray();
        }  
        return array(
            'result'    => $result,
            'totalRows' => $totalCount,
            'nextFeed'  => $nextFeed
        );
```

using v2.9 version, what parameter I should pass for $response->next(); help me if I am wrong .

Comment: Why are you trying to feed the _meta data_ into next()? It needs to be the graph edge object itself.

Comment: ya but if i pass 'nextFeed'=>$feedEdge  i am getting response as null

Comment: @CBroe, sir if I pass 'nextFeed'=>$feedEdge the response will be object{ }. I decoded $feedEdge then the response will be array of facebook posts, it will not contain paging array...can you please guide me to proceed further?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for this question...

If any one is trying for same try below code.

```
        $result = array();
        if(empty($_nextFeed)){ 
            $response = $fb->get('/me/feed?fields=id,message&limit=' . $_pagination->limit); 
            $feedEdge = $response->getGraphEdge();

            foreach ($feedEdge as $status) {
                $result[] = $status->asArray();
            }

            $nextFeed = $response->getGraphEdge()->getMetaData();
        }else{
            //to get until time stamp form next url
            $nextURl=parse_url($_nextFeed['paging']['next']);
            parse_str($nextURl['query'], $URL);

            $response = $fb->get('/me/feed?fields=id,message&limit='.(($_pagination->limit)+1).'&until='.$URL['until']); 
            $feedEdge = $response->getGraphEdge();

            foreach ($feedEdge as $status) {
                $result[] = $status->asArray();                    
            }
            //because result repeats last array of previous request
            array_splice($result,0,1);

            $nextFeed = $response->getGraphEdge()->getMetaData();
        }

        return array(
            'result'    => $result,
            'totalRows' => $totalCount,
            'nextFeed'  => $nextFeed
        );
```

It works :)